# How to do load test pages on jmeter which are accessible only after logged in

Tags: testing, authentication, jmeter, html

I want to do load test using jmeter the Login form and the page that is accessible by user after logged in. I am not getting what are the settings need to do on jmeter to test the page that looks after logged in, please explain how much you can.

The page is like `homepage/mymatches.php?page=4`.

Answer (score 0):

you will have do the following to test the pages

1. Correlations refer: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html
2. add a cookie manager to your test script.

by doing correlations using "regular expression extractor" you will be able to get/extract value of parameters from a response body/data of homepage after login and pass the same to subsequent pages where it is required.

http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.com/2011/12/correlation-regular-expression.html

hope this will help